# Is there any way to persist the usage stats of a router even if it reboots due to power failure?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, switch

I have a router (Tp-Link WR841N) for home use. I need to be aware of how much bandwidth is used in a particular time period(for example- a month) to avoid data caps applied by ISP.

I can monitor my usage from each individual device and sum up, but I want to know if it can be done directly from router, which probably would be a lot easier to check frequently.

The router usually maintains a statistics of received/sent bytes but after a reboot it looses all those data and starts counting from zero again. These reboots are actually from power failures not manual reboot, and that power failure is somewhat frequent- three or four times a day. (I can use an UPS/IPS for continuous power supply but that sometimes fails to cover the span of power outage too!)

So can anyone help me with a way to persist these usage stats of router?

Comment: not necessarily a useful answer, but I use a router with a hard drive [specifically a Sophos UTM]; data survives power-outs.

Comment: Another not useful answer, usually a data cap from an ISP just means that once you reach your cap you'll be throttled down. You'll still have Internet access, it'll just be slowed down significantly. Most people just use what they can, while they can, and then live without the large downloads until it resets again. The reason being that this will give them the maximum overall download capacity for the month (even if it is a little slower the last week or so).

Comment: I do not have a full solution, but I would consider setting up another (stateful) server which frequently queries your router via SNMP and keeps updated total values. I doubt you can achieve your purpose relying solely on a cheap consumer router.

Comment: Just looked at your routers sales page and notices that your router DOES have long term storage in the form of a USB drive. Wouldn't it be nice if it had a way to do what Telsujins' router does using that?

Comment: @giomasce you mean setting up that server locally right? That'd require a machine be live for the whole time which is again interrupted by power failures. I thought about keeping a script running from cloud that makes requests to the router periodically but that'd be a heavy waste of bandwidth. Another way is to set up auto email (that feature is available in my router) so that it emails after every x period, and then process those emails and calculate the used amount- it also seems like an overkill.

Comment: @krowe I don't know which page you looked at, but my router(Tp-link WR841N) doesn't have long term storage in form of a USB drive. If you did find one such page, please share.

Comment: http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR841N

Comment: @krowe I did check that page, nothing about "long term storage in the form of a USB drive"

Comment: You are right, I've misinterpreted that picture on the page. Reading through it I find no indication of a USB port on the device.